# Why isn't cxf json marshaing fields with null value

Tags: json, cxf

cxf version 2.2.7.
json string only contains not null value, but not contains null value properties, e.g.:

```
class Bean {String field1;String field2}

Bean bean = new Bean();
bean.setField1("value1");
```

after marshaing, result json is:

```
{"field1":"value1"}
```

I expect json to be:

```
{"field1":"value1","field2":""}
```

Thanks !

Comment: why do you expect that? "" is not the same as null.

Comment: {"field1":"value1","field2":null} or {"field1":"value1","field2":"null"} is ok, but what I got is {"field1":"value1"}

Comment: CXF incorporates a JSON library. That library has some defaults. If you don't like them, configure them differently.

Comment: I use org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JSONProvider,but can't found related options:unwrapped,wrapperName,wrapperMap,dropRootElement,dropCollectionWrapperElement,ignoreMixedContent,writeXsiType,readXsiType,ignoreNamespaces

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible to map null values in Jettison (default JSON provider). However, if you switch to [Jackson](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-Jackson) then you get what you want. Jackson maps null values to *null*.

In order to achieve that add the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And replace org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider with org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.

The result is:

```
{"field1":"value1","field2":null}
```